# I want a navbar to shrink when I scroll on a webpage

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, scroll

Right now this code does the opposite of what I want it to do. It enlarges the navbar when I scroll.

```
  scrollFunction();
};

function scrollFunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 80 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 80) {
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.padding = "80px 100px";
    document.getElementById("logo").style.fontSize = "25px";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.padding = "0px -200px";
    document.getElementById("logo").style.fontSize = "35px";
  }
}
```

Comment: Is your navbar a fixed element? You could achieve this by using CSS transition properties and adding/removing a class when the scrollTop gets to your threshold.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to add the bootstrap class `navbar-fixed-top` to your nav-bar
or make your CSS and JS in the form:

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(document).scrollTop() > 50) {
    $('nav').addClass('shrink');
  } else {
    $('nav').removeClass('shrink');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```css
body {
  padding-top: 50px;
}

nav a {
  padding-top: 20px !important;
  padding-bottom: 20px !important;
  font-size: 18px;
}

nav .navbar-toggle {
  margin: 13px 15px 13px 0;
}

.navbar-brand {
  font-size: 30px;
}



nav.navbar.shrink {
  min-height: 35px;
}

nav.shrink a {
  padding-top: 10px !important;
  padding-bottom: 10px !important;
  font-size: 15px;
}

nav.shrink .navbar-brand {
  font-size: 25px;
}

nav.shrink .navbar-toggle {
  padding: 4px 5px;
  m
```